# Java DnD - Java Component to .Net Component

Tags: java, .net, jtree, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to use Java drag and drop to drag an object from a JTree into a native .NET component that is embedded in my app.  This .NET component only accepts File objects, so I'm having trouble with the DnD's Transferable object.  Anyone know how I can make this Transferable "look" like a file to this .Net component?

p.s.  I need this answer as *Quickly* as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do is to provide a [DataFlavor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html) that is compatible between Java and .net. Or, to make things more clear, your [Transferable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html) must handle a DataFlavor that your .net application sends to your java one. As an example, using the [javaRemoteObjectMimeType](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#javaRemoteObjectMimeType) would allow you to use a String representation of the file name that your .,net application could handle.

In fact, the only thing your Java application may provide is a list of DataFlavor. it's your .net application's job to find a DataFlavor that is suitable.